# InstagramAPI利用の申請について

Tags: instagram

WebサイトからInstagramAPIを利用してユーザのフォロー・フォロー解除を行うため、
https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116
から何度か申請を行ってみたのですが、
「・does not fall into the approved use cases.」
との返信が返ってきて、どのようにシステムを修正、もしくは、申請をすればいいのかわかりませんでした。
本家のサイト以外でも、API申請の参考になるようなことやURLなどはないでしょうか？

また、フォームに「業務用サービスを提供するアプリ」に限定とありますが、「業務用サービスを提供するアプリ」とはどのようなアプリを指すのかがわかりませんでした。
こちらについても参考になることやURLなどありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

差し支えない範囲で結構ですがどのようなアプリケーションを作成/申請中でしょうか？

基本的には本家以外に参考になるリソースはありませんので、

> - Media rights management: for example a platform for media publishers and brands to request permission from the Instagram Community to use Instagram content.
> - Social media management: for example, a platform to help businesses integrate Instagram in their social media workflow.

この２つの例に合致するものを申請するしか無いかと。（基本的にB2Bですね

また、

> At this time we are approving only applications that have a clearly established portfolio of businesses. Please do not submit a request if you are still in development or if you are not an established business.

作成中のアプリケーションでは申請できないようです。

Comment: 一旦は次のようなことを考えています。

・ユーザやハッシュタグを指定して検索後、該当ユーザを一括でフォロー
・自分を未フォローのユーザーのフォロー解除
・ハッシュタグ検索した画像の中から、自分をフォローしているユーザを見つける

Answer (score -1):

こちらのサイトが大変参考になりますよ。
Instagram APIでwebサービスを作りたい全ての人に向けて書きました　https://syncer.jp/instagram-api-matome#content-12-1

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
回答いただいたURLは私自身も開発する際に参考にさせていただきました。

ただ、求めている回答としては、権限の申請フォームの許可が通るために参考になる内容を求めています。

v1/users/{ユーザーID}/relationship
を利用して、フォロー・フォローの解除ができるか確認したいのですが、申請が許可されていないと動作テストができないので、申請が通るようにしたいということです。